# android - add app info to list of items in google search

Tags: android, search, search-engine, google-search

There is an google app installed called "Google". Its a lite blue icon and its used to perform different searches natively on your device. I would like my app  to be listed as an item searched when user does  google search on a Android device.  So my app would be added to the list of resources searched as long as its installed on the users device. Is any of this possible? I can check the box to have the app added to the list of apps searched but i want the option available by default once the app is installed. Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

And finally, I would like my app to have a default check mark in this list so I can be searchable by default on install:

[image]

I've already added a meta-data tag for searchable resources but i want it to search by default. I'm using a system app if that helps. Also, I'd like the content of the app to be searchable.

Also, even if I manually check the box to have my app searchable no data shows up. Take a look at this screen shot of firefox being searched. It has actually data showing up (from web history/cache). My app shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: On my nexus 7, with Android 4.4.2, this "just happens" by default. For example, my test App is called "L2", and when I type that in the search box, it is the first item on the list. My guess is some kind of indexing happens at some point, so new apps may not appear straight away.

Comment: i think there is a bot called googlebot that can crawl through my app content and display searchable resources but i have to have my app on google play i believe.  My app is a system app so its not on google play its pre-installed, there must be some priviledge i can use to get this to work.

Comment: CommonsWare if your available could you help me ?